# Дублирование <thead> в HTML ninja

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

Когда выстраиваю таблицу через thead и вставляю данные через {{ }} в tbody все работает нормально [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я добавляю в базе еще одну строку, выходит следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы thead не дублировался?

HTML code

```
{% extends 'main/doki.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="groupcont">

        {% for el in groups %}

            <div class="disian-camp">
                <table class="disian-campe">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Номер группы</th>
                            <th>ФИО Куратора</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ el.titleid }}</td>
                            <td>{{ el.titlegroup1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ el.titlecurator }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить, что нужно поместить цикл внутрь таблицы:

```
{% extends 'main/doki.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="groupcont">

      <div class="disian-camp">
        <table class="disian-campe">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>Номер группы</th>
              <th>ФИО Куратора</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for el in groups %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ el.titleid }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.titlegroup1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ el.titlecurator }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Действительно, большое спасибо

Comment: @adjutantee, если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой (верхняя-левая часть ответа) как "правильный"